# Syntax of documentation

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain me what does (callback[, thisObject]); mean in [typescript documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_filter.htm)?

I'am more interested in bracets itself [, ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that's not the TypeScript documentation. [This is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/).

Second, TypeScript doesn't introduce any functions, so to look up function definition, signatures, parameters and return types, you should go to the JavaScript documentation, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) ([specific documentation for `.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

Having said all that, *usually*, in documentation and tutorials, square brackets around a parameter indicate that it's optional. `callback` is a parameter you must pass, but `thisObject` is not.